# Why does bulkDelete not work with no error?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots, bulk

I've tried to look for typo and other inaccuracies and tried to add permission requirement for the prune command but still, the ping pong and the "not a valid number" replies work but not the prune when I enter the amount.

Details: I'm trying to make a Discord bot that can prune based on input. I use DJS v12 and follow(ed) this guide https://v12.discordjs.guide/creating-your-bot/commands-with-user-input.html#number-ranges

```
if (!msg.content.startsWith(prefix) || msg.author.bot) return;
if (!msg.member.hasPermission("BAN_MEMBERS")) {
  msg.channel.send("You don\'t have permission.");
}
const args = msg.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split('/ +/');
const cmd = args.shift().toLowerCase();
  if (cmd === `ping`) {
    msg.reply('pong.');
  } else if (cmd === `prune`) {
    if (!msg.guild.me.hasPermission("MANAGE_MESSAGES")) return;
    const amount = parseInt(args[0]) + 1;
    
    if (isNaN(amount)) {
      return msg.reply('Not a valid number.');
    } else if (amount <= 1 || amount > 100) {
      return msg.reply('Please input a number between 1 and 99.');
    }
  msg.channel.bulkDelete(amount, true).catch(err => {
        console.error(err);
        msg.channel.send('Error!');
   });
  }
});
```

Comment: Typos: `.split('/ +/')` should be `.split(/ +/)` as it's a regular expression, and there is a missing `)` in `if (!msg.guild.me.hasPermission("MANAGE_MESSAGES") return`, so it should be `if (!msg.guild.me.hasPermission("MANAGE_MESSAGES")) return`.

Comment: @ZsoltMeszaros Thank you, I completely missed the split(). I also missed the ) when writing the question. One question though, would it work if I didn't put the quotation mark?

Comment: Yes, it will work without single quotes. `/ +/` is a regular expression, it means split by one or more whitespace. I prefer this over single `" "` as it works as expected even if the user adds some unnecessary spaces between arguments. Check out the difference between `'one two   three'.split(' ')` and `'one two   three'.split(/ +/)` in your browser's console. The first one returns an array with five items (two of them are empty strings, while the second one returns an array with the three items; `one`, `two`, and `three`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why your prune command doesn't work, is because of your command parsing. `args` is always `null` whereas `cmd` always contains the whole string.

So if you enter `$prune 3`, your `args` will be empty and `cmd` contains `prune 3`. That's why your `if` here:

```js
else if (cmd === `prune`)
```

doesn't match (if you specified arguments) and your prune command never gets executed.

To fix that, you have change your command parsing:

```js
const cmd = msg.content.split(" ")[0].slice(prefix.length);
const args = msg.content.split(" ").slice(1);
```

---

Note: Also you seem to have a typo in your question:

```js
if (!msg.guild.me.hasPermission("MANAGE_MESSAGES") return;
//                           Missing ")" here ----^
```

So change that line to

```js
if (!msg.guild.me.hasPermission("MANAGE_MESSAGES")) return;
```

Comment: thank you so much. It works now! May I know how to learn more about this stuff? Is there a source I could refer when I have no clue why my Discord bot codes don't work?

Comment: @Miku Glad I could help :) Stuff like that mostly comes with experience. In this case I thought it was weird that nothing was printed on an invalid command. So I used `console.log` to verify if the code block is called along with all the information I expect to have in it.